# YAML to PO/MO for PHP internationalization

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, twig, yaml

I want to internationalize my PHP site, using Twig and gettext. I succeeded into setting it up but the process is boring : a PO file must be edited with PoEdit (e.g.) so that it is converted to MO, then the server has to be restarted or the cache emptied.

I would like something easier, like in Symfony : editing a YAML file, then a library would automatically translate it and empty the cache. I guess this is what Symfony does, as it is also based on Twig.

Yet I couldn't find any existing solution, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

All Simfony2's Components are decoupled from the framework and can be implemented anywhere. So if you like the Symfony2 translation system you can implement the [Translator component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/index.html) in your php project (with any other symfony's component you want).

It's better than reinventing the wheel isn't it?

Comment: This is great ! However I am not sure that it will also work with Twig, which needs an MO file explicitly ?

Comment: Absolutely not. In symfony twig works great with Translator component and you can decide if use files (yaml, xml, other) or on DB.

Answer (score 0):

Localization/internationalization is trivial with the Symfony translation component. It's a standard component so you don't have to add anything, just understand how to configure and use it.

In a nutshell, you create translation files for any language you want to support then simply wrap your text in twig translation blocks `{% trans %}Text To Translate{% endtrans %}` or run variables through the translator filter `{{ myVar|trans }}`. Symfony then translates the text to whatever `_locale` is specified by the client's browser.

Read [Using the Symfony Translator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html) for more information.